# How to configure multiple enviroments in NX nrwl (angular) with multiple apps

Tags: angular, environment-variables, package.json, nrwl-nx

What are the best practices to setup multiple enviroments in nx (nrwl) workspace with multiple frontend apps? I have have DEV, UAT and PROD enviroments and how I can configure just run afftected project in development mode and please advice on the script to run the build

package.json

```
"scripts": {
...
 "start": "ng serve",
 "start:uat": "ng serve --configuration=uat",
 "build:prod": "npx nx affected --prod --base-href ./ --target=build --parallel --max-parallel=3",
 "build:uat": "npx nx affected --configuration=uat --base-href ./ --target=build --parallel --max-parallel=3",
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "configurations": {
      "prod": {
        "browserTarget": "car-store:build:production"
      },
      "dev": {
        "browserTarget": "car-store:build:dev"
      },
      "test": {
        "browserTarget": "car-store:build:test"
      },
      "uat": {
        "browserTarget": "car-store:build:uat"
      }
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "dev"
  }
}
```